# I don't know how to make the boss of a platformer in Godot 4.2

Tags: godot4

I want to make a boss that can attack and summon enemy
I tried using state... to do it but it didn't work
and I watched them do it, the videos I watched were only the 4.0 version so please help me complete the boss, I just hope I can finish it

Comment: Why did you tag this as a unity question if it's about godot?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.